# udevadm vs linux hotplug

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, udev

I am a bit confused with the questions listed below:

1. While I execute `udevadm` on my desktop, it is able to listen `uevent` sent from kernel.
   I think before the execution of `udevadm`, it will check the availability of `udevd`. 
   That means, if the `udevd` is not available on my desktop, `udevadm` will not be able to work.
   Is my thinking correct?
2. To have the same functionality of `udevadm`, I found that linux also provides another way
   to archive this. It's called `netlink`. What confuses me is If I do things this way, I could have exactly the same thing that I have by using `udevadm`. Hence, what's the difference between `udev` vs. `netlink socket`?

`socket(PF_NETLINK, SOCK_DGRAM, NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT);` <----The socket I created to listen to `uevent`.

---

Thanks for avd's feedback. I still have some questions to ask after having your feedback.

1. There are not only `udevd` can listen message from kernel, but also `udevadm` does. 
   Is my thinking correct? Or udevadm is only to manage `udevd`.
2. By setting up the socket binding to the `NETLINK_KOBJECT_UEVENT`, the user space code can also listen uevent sent from kernel. At this point, It seems I have no reason to choose `udev` to complete this function. Is there any different between these two approaches?
3. In user space, Can two different processes listen to `uevent` simultaneously? Can `netlink` send the message to these processes in the same time?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Yes, you're right. `udevadm` is to manage `udevd`.
2. This is where you're really confused. Let me clarify this. `udev` is userspace device manager. udev is responsible for your devices to appear in /dev directory. It's also responsible for hotplug functionality. To make things done udev works by receiving messages from kernel. Kernel sends messages via netlink socket. Netlink is just IPC facility implemented as separate socket family specifically for kernel to userspace interaction. So kernel sends messages of special format (uevent) over netlink socket. On the other site (in userspace) there must be someone who is listening for this messages and that's what udev does. Main part of `udev` is udev daemon - `udevd`. That daemon listens for that messages and creates special device files under /dev path and provide to you (linux user) interface to manage devices and hotplug (udev rules).

I've answered related question - check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803469/uevent-sent-from-kernel-to-user-space-udev/22813783#22813783).

Extra answers:

1. From udevadm manpage:

   > udevadm expects a command and command specific options. It controls
   >   the runtime behavior of systemd-udevd, requests kernel events, manages
   >   the event queue, and provides simple debugging mechanisms.

   So it's just a managing tool though it can requests kernel event on admin command.
2. (I might not understand you question correctly). You can write your own daemon to listen for uevents. That's what [gentoo's mdev](https://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Mdev) does.
3. Netlink allows you to provide multiple listeners for netlink messages. But it depends on a way that kernel socket sends message (unicast, multicast, broadcast) and netlink family. Netlink itself is a collection of families, so it may depends on what netlink you are using. For example, NETLINK_GENERIC family allows you to bind multiple userspace sockets for messages and you will receive that messages. I think the best way to answer this question is to write some simple listening code (probably with some help of *libudev*)

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question, would you mind to provide more feedbacks?