# android vold mechanism in the main function

Tags: android, netlink

By going through the code of vold,

I found there are a couple of lines of code in main.cpp (system/vold/main.cpp) that I dont get the real function of these.

Those are..

1.

```
vm->setBroadcaster((SocketListener *) cl);

nm->setBroadcaster((SocketListener *) cl);
```

---

2.

```
coldboot("/sys/block");
```

Why vold does a coldboot here?

---

Could anyone explain a bit about why vold does this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found out the answer for the first question.

vm->setBroadcaster((SocketListener *) cl);

nm->setBroadcaster((SocketListener *) cl);

In this case, VolumeManager and NetlinkManager need to send the notify to MountService which is in framework layer.  Hence, CommandListener acts as a broadcaster for vm and nm.  : )

Answer (score 1):

THe coldboot is done for coldplug devices by sending "add" to uevent files in /sys/block tree.

As described in [uevent sent from kernel to user space (udev)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803469/uevent-sent-from-kernel-to-user-space-udev)