# What does **uevent** stands for?

Tags: linux, kernel

As per the title, I would like to know the elaboration.

After googling, found that 'uevent' stands "userspace event".

Is this correct?

Thanks.

Comment: It is a *netlink message*. See [uevent sent from kernel to user space (udev)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22813783/1983854).

Comment: From context I would agree. ["uevent is just string of some special format that is sent via netlink socket"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22803469/uevent-sent-from-kernel-to-user-space-udev)

Comment: he didnt ask what it is though, he asked what the acronyms mean.

Comment: @hedgehog: you are right. I was reading about "ueventd" of android and found that the name is little bit  strange.
In fact I want to learn about "ueventd" and looking for some good reference.

Thanks.

Comment: i suppose what the guys provided you is sufficient for you, or you need sth more?

Comment: @hedgehog: Okay, let me check those in details and will be back if needed more.

Answer (score 2):

Thats correct it stands for `User Space Event`, but you are so off topic for stackoverflow... :)